# Creating new variable with keyword count in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column/variable that consists entirely of text/strings.

I would like to create a new column that counts the number of times a keyword appears in the other column, for example:

keyword: 'the'

Column A: ['the dog', 'cat', 'the tree']

New Column: [1,0,1]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str.count(keyword)
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly!

Comment: BTW, I tried df['new'] = df['col'].count(keyword) before but it didn't work without the ".str". What does the ".str" do?

Comment: @AlexTheBoy - `str` mean in `pandas` text function, I guess for distinguish from function from pure python, because same names.

Comment: @AlexTheBoy - Also you can check [working with text data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html)